# Why does Set.add not return an object?

Tags: java

Why does [Set.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) not return the object you are trying to add, or an object that is equal to the one you are trying to add if it is already in the set?

I could have an object with two properties, but only one of these properties is considered in the `hashcode()/equals()` method (and then use the property I do not consider for `hashcode()/equals()`.

A simple answer is that Set extends the Collection interface, but that is not satisfying; then the question is why `Set` does not have an additional method that accomplishes what I want it to do, e.g.: `set.addObject()`.

I know I can use [Map.getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-), but then I need to specify the two parameters of the Map.

Comment: Other than the slight inconvenience of not being able to write (`T x = set.add(new T());`, what is the problem here?

Comment: I'm a little confused with your question, you're asking why `set.add(E e)` does not return the object your're trying to add. I would assume because it was not implemented this way. I would assume that the boolean it returns would be enough information no?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth that is what I mean with the last paragraph in my question; that I have to use a Map with two parameters, but I do not want to map anything.

Comment: @NiekT. That is what I mean with the third paragraph. The returned object could have additional properties that are not set in the object you are trying to add.

Comment: I've voted to close this as "primarily opinion-based" as it's not clear what practical problem we're solving here.  The existing API is what it is, and whether or not an extension (`addObject`) to the API would be a good idea is basically an opinion-based debate (especially given that we're really talking about avoiding 3 lines of boilerplate).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I agree that it looks like "primarily opinion-based", but then my question is whether or not it is bad practice to have a Map<T,T> to solve my problem. This is a consequence of my question and should be addressed here imho.

Comment: Ok - then it may be worth re-wording your question to focus on the practical aspects ;)  (One could imagine the question essentially being "What is the most concise way to achieve a `Set` equivalent to `Map.getOrDefault`?")

Answer (score 4):

> A simple answer is that Set extends the Collection interface, but that is not satisfying

Satisfying or not, that *is* the answer to why `add` returns a `boolean` rather than the `Object` already in the `Set`; `Collection.add` returns a boolean to indicate whether the underlying collection was changed.

In general, what would you return to indicate that the element wasn't added, bearing in mind that "already in the collection" isn't the only reason for not adding an element?

The question of why there is not `addObject` method is quite separate, and opinion-based: *you* might consider it useful, but the API designers either:

- Didn't consider adding it, because they didn't see the need;
- Considered it, but decided it didn't carry its weight, since you can do it by other means on the rare occasions when you want such functionality.
- Considered that it might be useful, but were then unable to modify the interface to add a new method, as that would break existing implementations of `Set`.

  This is obviously possible now that interfaces can have default method implementations; but then we're back to the other two reasons above.

---

Actually, I take back what I say above "that "already in the collection" isn't the only reason for not adding an element".

According to [the Javadoc of `Collection.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)):

> Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the call. (Returns false if this collection does not permit duplicates and already contains the specified element.)

So, OK, it *should be* the only reason. But then you've got to wonder why it would be useful, say, for a `List` to return the element you've just added.

Comment: Couldn't you use the `==` operator to see if the object was added?
I do not want to use a `List` since you can add an object multipe times.
Furthermore a good use case is indeed the cache, discussed by Joop Eggen.

Comment: @meijuh - But then you're back to a verbose solution.  So it's really a question of which is the more common use-case (i.e. which should the API be optimised in favour of).  At any rate, the existing API is what it is - debating whether it should be something different is moot.

Answer (score 3):

**It indeed would be nice.**

A simple usecase would be a **cache**, so no duplicate instances are used:

This must currently be implemented as follows:

```
class Shared<T>
    private final Map<T, T> map = new HashMap<>();

    public T share(T obj) {
        T old = map.get(obj);
        if (old == null) {
            map.put(obj, obj);
            old = obj;
        }
        return old;
    }
}
```

But when Set.addObject would return the old object or when null added object:

```
    private final Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();

    public T share(T obj) {
        return set.addObject(obj);
    }
```

The algebraic completeness of Set, having all operations available, indeed lacks that functionality.

Comment: @AndyTurner that I used already, but the return value may be null, isn't it? Is nicer though

Comment: This is exactly the use case I am encountering. Why do you name the method `share()`? Also could the body of `share()` no simply be `return map.getOrDefault(obj);`? The latter part of you answer is a bit vague, is adding `null` a problem?

Comment: `getOrDefault` does for a non-existing key return the parameter but not store it. `putIfAbsent` and `getOrDefault` are too new to be categorized well. `put` returns null for non-existing keys, where it then has to be added. The name `share` is for implying that the first object added will be shared with all following calls. Ideal for an XML/Excel document with many repeated strings.